# An example of a geometry invariant but that is not a topology invariant?

Tags: differential-geometry

> Can you give me an example of a geometry invariant but that is not a topology invariant?

The only idea that I had is the Gaussian curvature but I am not sure if it's true. It was a question asked by my professor in a differential geometry class.

Comment: The cross-ratio in projective geometry...

Comment: Diameter, volume, injective to radius,

Comment: Gaussian curvature is a great example. On a compact surface its integral is a topological invariant, but not its pointwise values.

Comment: It seems that geodesic completeness fits the bill. One can place two metrics on a given manifold, one complete and the other not. One part of the Nomizu-Ozeki theorem does say that any Riemannian metric is conformally equivalent to a complete metric, so I don't think this is really interesting, though...

Comment: Almost any geometric invariant you can think of. Only a few are topologically invariant.